# Creating objects of a class within the class

Tags: java, string, forms, oop, class

Quick question about the code below:

```
public class Test {

    public final static Test t1 = new Test("test 1");
    public final static Test t2 = new Test("test 2");
    public final static Test t3 = new Test("test 3");

    private String s;

    private Test (string s1) {
        s = s1;
    }
}
```

I am confused as to whether this code will create *unlimited instances* of itself?

Comment: I suggest that you look at these answers as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-java

Answer (score 3):

No the VM will not: `"create unlimited instances of itself."`

Your static fields (`t1`, `t2` and `t3`) will be created once (each) on `Class` level, and not on `Instance` level.
Your 3 fields will be shared between all instances.

Comment: Simple and explains it all. +1

Answer (score 1):

The code will not create unlimited instances of itself because the variables `t1`, `t2` and `t3` are **initialized statically** (meaning once when the class gets loaded, not once for each instance), because of the **`static` declaration** in combination with the **assignment in the declaration**.

You may want to read up on what exactly `static` does.

**Useful note:**

The below example, on the other hand, while using a `static` variable, would cause it to be initialized when an instance gets created (because of the **assignment in the constructor**) and would thus cause a **StackOverflowError**:

```
public class Test {
   static Test t1;
   Test () {
      t1 = new Test();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

static members are not part of the created object. So there will be no infinite creation of `Test` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking it because the static (t1, t2 and t3) declarations give you the impression that each instance will have their own copies of these variables.

Actually, this is not what will happen. Static variables are not created per instance. Only one instance of them ever exists in a JVM.

Answer (score 0):

If it would have been something like

```
public class Test {
   // no static so these are created for each instance of A or each time constructor is called
   public final Test t1 = new Test("test 1");
   public final Test t2 = new Test("test 2");
   public final Test t3 = new Test("test 3");

   private String s;

   private Test (string s1){
      s = s1
   }

}
```

Then it would have created unlimited instances as `t1`,`t2` and `t3` are *instance level variables*.

But in your case they are `static` so instances are created on *class loading time* and not with each instance so **no unlimited instances**.